# "Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'." when using filenames with "-"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I keep getting this error message:

> C:\Minted3\app\src\main\res\drawable\diamond-app-icon-master.jpg
>
> :Error: '-' is not a valid file-based resource name character: File-based resource names must contain only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore

How can I fix this issue? I've tried changing the name of the image in the drawable folder on my hardrive to `diamond_icon_master.jpg`, but that just leads to a series of new additional errors.

This is my XML activity:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#303F9F"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/title"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/diamond_image" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: As the error says, you can't use - in your filename. Post the additional errores that you see

Answer (score -1):

Must not contain "-"

> ...only lowercase a-z, 0-9, or underscore.